# Meaning of Scattering-Amplitudes "time-volume"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section, normalization

I've been reading [this book](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/%7Eywu/QFT0.pdf) by Schwichtenberg as I re-learn QFT. My question is general, but applies easiest to the scattering amplitude at first order in the $\phi^4$-theory for $k_1,k_2\rightarrow k_1,k_2$-scattering (page 418), where we encounter the expression \begin{equation}A^{(1)}=-i\langle 0\vert a(k_1)a(k_2)\int\text{d}^4x\,:\phi^4(x): a^\dagger(k_1)a^\dagger(k_2)\vert 0\rangle=-i\lambda V_4\end{equation}where $V_4$ ist the spacetime-volume $V=\int\text{d}^4x$. Since our momentum states are not normalized, $\langle 0\vert a(k)a^\dagger(q)\vert 0\rangle=2\omega_k(2\pi)^3\delta(\vec{q}-\vec{k})$, I'm not bothered by the space-volume $V_3=\int\text{d}^3x$ appearing, since it will drop out when we normalize the expression about our "momentum-state-norm", i.e calculating $\frac{A^{(1)}}{\sqrt{\vert \langle k_1\vert k_1\rangle \vert^2\vert \langle k_2\vert k_2\rangle \vert^2}}$ or just using a normalized superposition of momentum-states. But the time-volume will remain, i.e. $V_0=\int\text{d}t$.

My question is simple: How do people deal with this time-volume. I know that if I calculate cross-sections, through long calculations in the end no arbitrary volume of any kind can remain, of course. But there has to be a more direct way to see this, i.e. to interpret this time-volume as "something". Many books gloss over such problems and simply state that the infinities will "drop out at the end", which is quite unsatisfying as you can imagine for a reader at beginner level.

*As an aside*: I think it is not super weird that a time dependence appears in our results, as we ask for a probability of a process happening in a certain ammount of time. And obviously this probabilty will increse as we increase the time the process is allowed to happen in. And effectively a scattering process will only happe during a short amount of time $\Delta t$ (at least thats what I assume). But this all seems very handwavy and yields no explanation of how to interpret the result above. Especially since the transition-rate $\Gamma=P/\Delta t$ would still depend on this time-volume, since $P\sim \vert A\vert^2\sim V_0^2$ and therefore $\Gamma\sim V_0$.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question might be too simple. But all references I went through didn't even bother discussing it, which is why I'm left searching for references that adress such problems.